# Один экземпляр класса

Tags: java

Как эффективно реализовать создание только одного экземпляра класса? Необходимо чтобы создавать можно было только один объект. Вот что получилось у меня

```
class Loader{
    private static int id = 0;
     static Loader newLoader(){
            if(id == 0){
                id++;
                return new Loader();
            }
            else
                return null;
    }
    private Loader(){

    }
}
```

Насколько это правильно? И Можно ли сделать так, чтобы метод `newLoader()` не возвращал `null` в случае наличия уже созданного объекта, а присваивал ссылке тот же объект? То есть  чтобы ссылка на объект не терялась.

Comment: ознакомтесь с паттерном [singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Одиночка_(шаблон_проектирования))

Comment: есть такой паттерн как [singleton](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129494/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы "изобрели" *singleton*, в интернете полно примеров реализации.

Самый простой пример:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я просто ещё не добрался до паттернов проектирования)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirovich, вам там хорошую ссылку по теме в комментариях привел Wolkodav. Определенно стоит ознакомиться.

Comment: Думаю вечером займусь.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд самый удобный способ в `java` создать `Singleton`:

```
public class Singleton {
     // приватный конструктор - из вне нельзя будет создать объект.
    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.HOLDER_INSTANCE;
    }

    static class SingletonHolder {
       private static final Singleton HOLDER_INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Советую прочитать статью «[Правильный Singleton в Java](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129494/)» на Хабрахабре.

Answer (score 1):

если говорить о синглтонах то есть вот такая реализация "из коробки"/ by classloader, хочу отметить что в отличие от примера выше тут не нужна синхронизация:

```
public enum Singleton {

    INSTANCE;

    public void someMethod(){
    }

}
```

но все же лучше использовать Dependency Injection

Answer (score 0):

Физическое ограничение в один экземпляр класса - это всегда плохо. Рано или поздно требуется второй с категорически иным наполнением, и тут начинаются пляски с выставлением новых данных, использованием класса, и возвратом всего на место. Хорошим тоном считается создать ровно один экземпляр класса и передавать его в программе между другими объектами (если это необходимо). В случае сложной структуры в этом может помочь [DI-контейнер](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131993/), задача которого заключается как раз в том, чтобы создавать сервисы, держать в себе ссылки на них, автоматом подставлять их в конструкторы свежесоздающихся сервисов и разрешать цепочки зависимостей. В случае, если созданием ваших сервисов занимается контейнер, вы можете быть уверены что внутри контейнера хранится только один объект вашего сервиса. Для Java можно использовать [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), например.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, singleton я считаю здесь не нужен! Каждый вызов `getInstance()` занимает наносекунды на проверку условия `if(...)`
Считаю, что данный вариант оптимален, ибо быстрее чем сразу не бывает:

```
class Cat {

    private static Cat cat = new Cat();

    private Cat() {
    }

    public void voice() {
        System.out.println("Meow :3");
    }

    public static Cat getInstance() {
        return cat;
    }

}
```

***Замечание:*** Отражения в Java в любом случае позволяют обойти всё, что вы придумаете для создания "единственного" экземпляра, и создать множество других ;)

Answer (score -4):

Я бы наверное так сделал:

```
class Loader{
    static Loader a = new Loader();
    public Loader(){
        return a;
    }   
}
```

Comment: конструктор ничего не возвращает

Comment: А! Точно. Ну значит так:  `class Loader{
    static Loader a = new Loader();
    public Loader getInstance(){
        return a;
    }   
}`